# Finding mode of a sorted array

Tags: c

I was hoping to get some input on how to correctly find the mode of a sorted array in C. Here's what I'm working with. First, my `freqDistrib` function:

```
void freqDistrib(int t[], int num) {
    int i, j, x;
    static int f[SIZE];

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Part C:\n");
    printf(" %-5s %-16s\n", "score", "frequency");
    printf(" %-5s %-16s\n", "-----", "---------");

    for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        x = t[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && x > t[j]) {
            t[j + 1] = t[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        t[j + 1] = x;
    } // sorts input in descending order

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        ++f[t[i]];
        if (t[i] != t[i + 1])
            printf(" %3d %7d\n", t[i], f[t[i]]);
    } // finds the frequency of each input and prints
}
```

and my mode function:

```
void modeScore(int t[], int num) {
    int i, j, max, mode;
    int f[SIZE];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        f[t[i]]++;
    }
    mode = 0;
    max = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        if (f[j] > max) {
            max = f[j];
            mode = j;
        }

    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Part F:\n");
    printf("%3d is mode\n", mode);
}
```

Output right now:

> 0 is mode

I realize that I need to compare the current frequency tally to a max, and if it is higher than set it equal to max. I just can't for the life of my figure out why this isn't working. Any input would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: One problem is that `int f[SIZE]; for (i = 0; i < num; i++) { f[t[i]]++; }` increments elements of the uninitialized array `f`, which leads to indeterminate (quasi-random) values being incremented.  Make sure `f` is zeroed before using it.  You can probably use `int f[SIZE] = { 0 };` to do that.

Comment: Try stepping through the code in a debugger and watching the variables. Compare the values you see in the debugger with the values you expect to see based on your understanding of what the code is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say the array is sorted, you don't need to create a temporary array to count the values.  Instead, you just need to traverse the input, keeping count of how many identical values you've seen in the current run.  At the end of the run, then compare the length of the run to the previous longest run, and update if the new run is longer.

(Actually, we update whenever the current run is longer, so we don't forget to update if the mode is the very last value).

Notice that we no longer need `SIZE` to bound our values; we can now work with the full range of `int` if we wish.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void modeScore(const int t[], int num)
{
    int start = 0;
    int mode = t[0];
    int score = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < num; ++i) {
        if (i - start > score) {
            // a longer run than the previous candidate
            score = i - start;
            mode = t[start];
        }
        if (t[start] != t[i])
            // we've reached a change in value
            start = i;
    }

    printf("Part F: %3d is mode (count %d)\n", mode, score);
}
```

You didn't provide a `main()`, so I adapted Jonathan Leffler's:

```
int main(void)
{
    int data[] =
    {
        /* random -n 40 0 9 | commalist -b '        ' -l 38 */
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5,
        5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8,
        8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9,
    };

    modeScore(data, sizeof data / sizeof data[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, the principal problem was that you did not initialize `f` in the function.

Here's working code which shows that was all the change that was necessary:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { SIZE = 100 };

static void modeScore(int t[], int num)
{
    int f[SIZE] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        f[t[i]]++;
    int mode = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
    {
        if (f[j] > max)
        {
            max = f[j];
            mode = j;
        }
    }

    printf("Part F: %3d is mode (count %d)\n", mode, max);
}

int main(void)
{
    int data[] =
    {
        /* random -n 40 0 9 | commalist -b '        ' -l 38 */
        7, 8, 3, 8, 5, 9, 5, 8, 9, 6,
        8, 0, 1, 8, 2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 3,
        3, 0, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 5, 9, 0,
        1, 9, 1, 7, 8, 0, 5, 4, 0, 8,
    };

    enum { DATA_SIZE = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    modeScore(data, DATA_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

For the given data, the output is:

```
Part F:   8 is mode (count 7)
```

(Funny coincidence: the first time I ran it — with slightly different data — the answer came back as `Part F:   0 is mode (count 7)`.  This was actually correct; I changed one of the zeros into an eight to produce the current result.)

Note that I would normally design the function to return the modal value, rather than have it do the printing.  As it stands, it can't be reused because the printing is not material to most code that wants to determine the mode.
The code also does not check that the values in `t` fall in the range `0`..`SIZE-1` (but it should).

The parameter order you use is traditional, but there is at least nominally some advantage to using:

```
void modeScore(int num, int t[num])
```

to express explicitly that the array `t` has `num` elements in it.  The size must precede its use in the array dimentson, though.

Comment: OT: `random -n 40 0 9 | commalist -b '        ' -l 38` is this a command?

Comment: It is on my machine, but I wrote both commands.  `random` is a C program that is quite complex because it can generate random 'words' with varying degrees of complexity; `commalist` is a shell script.  (The more complex bits of `random` are still a work in progress; though it's mostly fairly stable, there's room to think that the syntax used is abominable — and not complex enough for some of the tasks I'd like it to do.)  See my profile if you'd like copies of the source.